# Retrieve work items in recycle bin in TFS 2015 update 3(on premise)

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We are following the link: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/recycle-bin in order to retrieve the work items in recycle bin using TFS Rest Api, but this doesn't seem to work.

Url format contains the "project" variable but the example url does not follow the same:
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}_apis/wit/recycleBin?api-version={version}

https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/recyclebin?api-version=1.0

The above request url points to version 1.0 but the link recommends version 3.0 which is confusing.

What is the correct url in order to fetch work items in Recycle bin,is there any other alternate way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by passing the version as 3.0-preview and not 1.0 in the url.

http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/{Team Project Collection}/{Team Project}/_apis/wit/recycleBin?api-version=3.0-preview